# Can I play video through my Apple TV and use my iPhone as "wireless" headphones?

Tags: windows-7, iphone, appletv, airplay

I have bought an Apple TV recently. I've got everything set up fine, but this is one thing I'd like to do that I can't seem to find a way!

In iTunes on my PC, I have some movies. Can I play the video from these movies onto my Apple TV (using AirPlay), but also stream the audio to my iPhone with some headphones plugged in? This way I can sit back and enjoy these movies from the comfort of my bed, late at night, without the rest of the household moaning.

I downloaded the AirSpeaker app for iPhone, then found out that iTunes itself can't stream video to multiple AirPlay sources, but it can do so with music (I wonder if there's a little hack that could fix this?). I've also played with AirFoil, which doesn't do video unfortunately.

I'm happy to use external software (preferably freeware) in place of iTunes and happy to download any other iPhone apps, etc.